# Do people in your circles/contacts see your downloaded apps in their recommendations?

Tags: google-play-store

is your app/movie/book history available to people in your circles/contacts by means of recommendations or some other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Recommendations in Play Store are based on different criteria. But, overall one can say that the following are some of the things which google takes into account when showing the recommendations to you or your friends,

- You/Your friend +1'ed an item on the Playstore.
- You/Your friend rated an item.
- Some recommendations are based on locality.
- Items that you have already installed/bought with your google account.
- Items that are top rated in different categories like Games, Apps, Movies, Music, Books etc.

Comment: i think i once read somewhere that your bought items are private to you.is it correct?

Comment: Can you provide me the source? I don't think so because recommendations are a way to market Play Store products. And when you do `rate` or `+1` the app when you bought it for free or paid version it will be displayed in you friend's recommendation list. So its better you  avoid `rating` or `+1` the app you buy and it wont be displayed else where on you friends or other people in your circles. ;)

Comment: so you are agreeing with me right?

Comment: yepp agreeing with you..you can follow my comment not to `rate` or `+1` any apps you buy for google to respect your privacy ;)